# jQuery add the sum for all childrens to parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I get the **sum of all images width** and add the width to `ul`?

This is not working. http://take.ms/Uymli

Here you can see my script: http://makeaplate.justapplications.co.uk/ under SIDEBADGES, click "sidebadge on left or right" than accordion.

I want to remove the horizontall scroll.

How can i do this ?

Html Code:

```
<dl class="accordion">
  <dt><a href="#">open</a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
        <!-- this list is generated with ajax -->
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <dt><a href="#">open</a></dt>
  <dd>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="" alt="" /></a></li>
    </ul>
  </dd>
  <!-- there's more ul's -->
</dl>
```

and this is the js:

```
$('.accordion a').click(function(e){
  $('.accordion dd').slideUp();
  $(this).parent().next().slideDown();

  // this is the code i need
  $sum = 0;
  $(this).children('img').each(function(){
        var liW = $(this).width(); // width of images
        var nrE = $(this).parent('li').length; // nr of li elements
        $sum += liW; // sum?
        $(this).parent('ul').css({width:$sum-(nrE*15)+'px'}); // 15px is margin-right for li
   });
});
```

Comment: could you please share CSS code you layout img ? i think there is a solution how to reach this goal without JS

Comment: Please create a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It would do it with overflow-x: none to avoid the horizontal scrollbar

Comment: @Evgeniy Ya, looks like an XY problem to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the images dimensions you must be sure, that they are loaded before. One trick is to use $(window).load, but indeed it can be slow to wait of all site ressources.

Another way is to look afte your images you want to inspect, if they are already loaded (no browser cache at first time loading the site). To make this easy I wrote a jQuery plugin:

```
if (typeof jQuery.fn.loaded === 'undefined') {
jQuery.fn.loaded = (function (options, callback) {

    var elements = this,
        defaults = {
            timeout: 0 //kein Timeout
        };
    if ($.isFunction(options)) {
        callback = options;
    } else {
        if (!$.isEmptyObject(options)) {
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        }
    }

    var dfd = new $.Deferred(),
        l = elements.length,
        i = 0;

    $.each(this, function () {
        if (typeof this.complete !== 'undefined') {
            if (!this.complete) {
                if (!$.isEmptyObject(options) && options.timeout > 0) {
                    //TODO: Timer der ein fail per Deferred Promise zurückgibt
                }
                $(this).load(function () {
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback.call(this);
                    }++i;
                    if (l == i) {
                        dfd.resolve(elements);
                    }
                });
            } else {
                if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                    callback.call(this);
                }++i;
                if (l == i) {
                    dfd.resolve(elements);
                }
            }

        }
    });

    return dfd.promise();

});
}
```

...

Usage example:

```
var $images = $('img');

var w = 0;
$images.each(function () {
   w += $(this).width();
});
console.log('Maybe while loading: ', w);

$.when($images.loaded()).then(function (el) {
   console.log('All images loaded now calculate the sum');
   var w = 0;
   $images.each(function () {
       w += $(this).width();
   });
   console.log('After loading all images Width is: ', w);
});
```

Hope this helps. The plugin uses the Deferred object to check if all images - which are selected - are loaded.

Here is a litte fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h37rm/4/ 
Try run it local or on your webserver, then you can really see the issue of beeing cached.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution for images with zero width with the comment above:

```
$('img').on("load", function(){

     adjustUl()      

});

function adjustUl(){

    $(".accordion").find("ul").each(function(){

        var sumOfWidth = 0;    

        $(this).find("img").each(function(){

             sumOfWidth += $(this).width();

        });     

        $(this).width(sumOfWidth);

    });

}
```

Comment: Problem with this code, if the images are not loaded already, the width will be 0.

Comment: Even with document.ready images still loading, use $(window).load instead. Or better use the $('img').on('loaded' events. In combine with deferred Object loop all images, after all are loaded then you can sum up all images with